# How to Overlay multiple rectangles

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, maps

I have a several Lat Long co-ordinate which specify a box around a region 
Eg:

```
LATITUDE 26.664503840000002 29.145674380000003,LONGITUDE -96.27139215 -90.40762858
```

I was looking at the Google Maps overlay of drawing a [Rectangle](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#Rectangles).

If I want to overlay multiple rectangles for different Lat/Longs should I create new bound objects and assign it to the overlay object ?

```
function initialize() {
  var 
  lat   = 29.145674380000003, // Should I calcuate the center or
                              // can I use of the min/max co-ordinates
  lng   = -90.40762858;
  zoom  = 4;
  // Basic
  var MapOptions = {
      zoom: zoom,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng( lat, lng ),
      disableDefaultUI: true,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),MapOptions);
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
      new google.maps.LatLng( 26.664503840000002, -96.27139215 ),
      new google.maps.LatLng( 29.145674380000003, -90.40762858 )
    );
  var overlay = new google.maps.Rectangle({
      map: map,
      bounds: bounds,
      strokeColor: "red",
      strokeWeight: 1,
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the example of how to add rectangles dynamically:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Rectangle Simple</title>
    <link href="/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
    <script>
      function initialize() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
          zoom: 11,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(33.678176, -116.242568),
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
        });

    var myBounds = new Array();
    myBounds[0] = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
            new google.maps.LatLng(33.671068, -116.25128),
            new google.maps.LatLng(33.685282, -116.233942));

    myBounds[1] = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
            new google.maps.LatLng(33.671068, -116.25128),
            new google.maps.LatLng(33.687282, -116.238942));
    myBounds[2] = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
            new google.maps.LatLng(33.671068, -116.25128),
            new google.maps.LatLng(33.688282, -116.238942));

    addRects(myBounds, map);
      }
    function addRects(bounds, map){
    for (var i=0; i<bounds.length; ++i) {
      var overlay = new google.maps.Rectangle({
          map: map,
          bounds: bounds[i],
          strokeColor: "red",
          strokeWeight: 1,
        });
    }
    }

      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>

<style>
#map_canvas {
    width: 600px;
    height: 400px;
}
</style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks can you look at my code .. if it possible to overlay multiple rectangles ?

Comment: add this to your example to get the second rectangle.

Comment: So there is no dynamic way to do this ? Like pushing all the bounds inside an array and passing the array object to overlay ?

Comment: Just create your own function for this. Function would take array of bounds and map and will dynamically create those rectangles and add to map.

Comment: I actually added the working example. Please mark as answered if this is what you needed.

Comment: Sure. You can do that, you need to iterate through the array of bounds and create (probably) an array of rectangles.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the source of the [linked sample](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/rectangle-simple), it actually provides a bounds.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Rectangle Simple</title>
    <link href="/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
    <script>
      function initialize() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
          zoom: 11,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(33.678176, -116.242568),
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
        });

        var rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle({
          strokeColor: '#FF0000',
          strokeOpacity: 0.8,
          strokeWeight: 2,
          fillColor: '#FF0000',
          fillOpacity: 0.35,
          map: map,
          bounds: new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
            new google.maps.LatLng(33.671068, -116.25128),
            new google.maps.LatLng(33.685282, -116.233942))
        });
      }

      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[Working example with your coordinates](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_rectangle-simpleA.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer ... I also created an working example :) I was wondering about the center. Is the center for the map or for the rectangle ?

Comment: how can I overlay multiple rectangles

Comment: Duplicate the var rectangle (better to give each one a different name) and change the bounds.

Comment: Sorry, missed your question about the center.  The center option for the map is the center of the map.  If you want the center of the bounds, there is a getCenter() method for [google.maps.LatLngBounds](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLngBounds) objects.